# Linq to SQl - single result

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have been playing with the Linq to Sql and I was wondering if it was possible to get a single result out? For example, I have the following:

```
using(DataClassContext context = new DataClassContext())
{
   var customer = from c in context.table
                  where c.ID = textboxvalue
                  select c;
}
```

And with this I need to do a foreach around the var customer but i know that this will be a single value! Anyone know how I could do a `textbox.text = c.name;` or something along that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
using(DataClassContext context = new DataClassContext())
{
var customer = (from c in context.table
where c.ID = textboxvalue
select c).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

This way you get 1 result or null if there isn't any result.

You can also use `Single()`, which throws an exception when there isn't a result.
`First()` will give you only the first result found, where `Last()` will give you only the last result, if any.

Here's an [Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx) of all Enumerable methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
var customer = context.table.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == textboxvalue);
```